# Bootstrap wells

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="well" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
    SOME OTHER CONTENT DIVS BLA BLA
</div>
```

My wells because height auto doesn't keep under all content and it stays by default size with no content...

And my content overflows it.

When I add `overflow:hidden` to wells I get what I need wells are all under whole content.

But when I need to overflow over well like for some dropup menu or something I can't do it because `overflow:hidden`

Is there way to say overflow hidden for all child divs except one with some unique id or something?

Comment: Have you tried setting the position to absolute for the child you are trying to overflow? If that's not working, try and give it a higher z-index than the container.

Comment: I tried both... Nothing is working because that overflow hidden I added but also it should take all content inside automatically right IDK why it doesn fill out

Comment: Thats why I tagged php as well maybe it is because I am echoing it with php on just html it works good